# Why by default Vite doesn't refresh upon scripts/css changes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vite

docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#blade-refreshing-on-save

They write:

> When the refresh option is true, saving files in the following
> directories will trigger the browser to perform a full page refresh
> while you are running npm run dev:
>
> ```
> app/View/Components/**
> lang/**
> resources/lang/**
> resources/views/**
> routes/**
> ```

Now I'm curious: why doesn't this list include paths to css/scss and js? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure why `resources/*` (`js` and `sass`/`css` locally) isn't listed, but saving a file in one of those directories locally does indeed trigger a Vite reload. How odd.

Comment: I think you don't need to define this if you are using the @vite directive as it defines the entry file which is for example ```app.js``` https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found out that vite does refresh in Laravel when you use the @vite directive in blade templates, and of course the files you want to be compiled must be configured as input in vite config.
Thus, I guess the docs refer to all the other directories that are meant to trigger page refreshes even when vite doesn't compile anything.
For example it can, for sure, be desiderable that the browser refreshes unpon blade components changes. Or even, don't know, for example models, or controllers, or other php parts, that are not compiled by vite but still maybe you could like them to trigger browser refreshes.

The defaults above are configurable, just pass to the refresh option an array with glob patterns instead of a boolean (as seen in docs linked above).